# Pycharm not showing all files from django external library

Tags: django, docker, django-templates, pycharm

In pycharm under external libraries I'm not able to see all files (e.g all templates are missing).

The external librarys are coming from a remote server (docker).
On the server itself, I'm able to see every file.

Pycharm

[image]

Docker container

```
root@fcb645e62162:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages# ls django/contrib/admin
__init__.py  actions.py  checks.py  exceptions.py  forms.py    locale      models.py   sites.py  templates     tests.py  views
__pycache__  apps.py     decorators.py  filters.py     helpers.py  migrations  options.py  static    templatetags  utils.py  widgets.py
```

Comment: Did you make a pycharm docker interpreter? https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/12/using-docker-in-pycharm/

Comment: yep. I have a remote interpreter setted up via ssh

Comment: and the Files are served from this remote folder

Comment: check that you are not hiding anything in settings: Settings | File Types --> Ignore files and folders

Comment: I dont because I can see the files with .html which are not coming from a remote source. In addition when I go to the remote folder of pycharm in the filesystem the templates folder is also missing.

Comment: Does anybody know a solution for this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Encountering the exact same issue with PyCharm 2017.1.1. I'm going through the Django tutorials (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial07/) and missing the 'templates' directory from my remote library in PyCharm. The file exists in the Docker container, but does not exist in PyCharm's cached directory.

Comment: Also having this issue. Really annoying to not see any base-templates for e.g. Django.

Comment: Doesn't the directory could merely created in Pycharm?

Comment: Some problem is in latest 2018.2 EAP Pycharm

Comment: pycharm just pulls source from remote python interpreters, it's not browsing the docker instance but making a local cache of the python files. You don't need to, nor should you, edit python library template files from site packages. Especially if your python is a docker as when the docker gets rebuilt all the packages will be fresh and your changes lost. Copy your templates to your template directory and use them there.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in the latest PyCharm build, but maybe there's something

special in your case that breaks it.
Try update version.
or go to Settings | Project Structure and add the folder with

your Django installation as a content root to your project.